# multidimensional arrays in VHDL

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, vhdl, xilinx

I want to do multiplication of 2 matrix,and I am trying to make an array of std_logic_vectors in VHDL.

```
package matrice is
type t11 is array (32 downto 0,0 downto 19) of unsigned(7 downto 0);<
type t1 is array (0 downto 19) of t11;
type t2 is array (0 downto 194) of unsigned(7 downto 0);








entity matrice_test is

Port      (clk      : in STD_LOGIC;a : in t1;b : in t2;multi :out t2);
end matrice_test;

architecture Behavioral of matrice_test is
type t11 is array (M_MAX-1 downto 0,0 downto O_MAX-1) of unsigned(N-1 downto 0);
type t1 is array (0 downto O_MAX-1) of t11; 
type t2 is array (0 downto N_MAX-1) of unsigned(N-1 downto 0);
```

The error that I am getting:

```
indexed name prefix type t11 expects 2 dimensions
```

Comment: This appears to be a synthesis error (ERROR:HDLCompiler:540). Provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also note that overloaded type declarations names t11, t1 and t2 in the architecture declarative region will not be compatible with and hide those found in package matrice (presumably used for ports a and b, lacking a context clause). Each declaration in VHDL is unique, they aren't the same type. Consider simulating your design first. Show complete error messages.

Comment: See IEEE Std 1076-2008 5.3.2.2 Index constraints and discrete ranges, para 4 "...If any of the discrete ranges defines a null range, any array thus constrained is a *null array*, having no elements...."

Answer (score 2):

I can't reproduce your error (how about submitting an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), but this

```
type t11 is array (323 downto 0,0 downto 19) of unsigned(7 downto 0);
```

should be this

```
type t11 is array (323 downto 0,0 to 19) of unsigned(7 downto 0);
--                                 ^
--                                 |
```

Comment: thank you for you request, during the simulation of my program I receive this error "indexed name prefix type t11 expects 2 dimensions" in this line type t11 is array (323 downto 0,0 to 19) of unsigned(7 downto 0);I tried to do "to" instead of downto  but I find the same error

Comment: Well @rola, as I cannot see anything else wrong with that line, I cannot help you unless you construct an MCVE. How about doing it on EDA Playground?

Comment: That line is valid VHDL. 0 downto 19 is a null range. Your answer is really a comment, nothing else is possible without an MCVE and full and specific error messages (presumably from synthesis). See IEEE Std 1076-2008 5.3.2.2 Index constraints and discrete ranges, para 4 "...If any of the discrete ranges defines a null range, any array thus constrained is a *null array*, having no elements...." The design specification doesn't appear functional and overloaded type declarations as architecture declarative items are not the same type even with the same dimensionality and element types.

Comment: @user1155120 You are right. I was thinking that in the receipt of more information (as an MCVE) it would morph into a more helpful answer.